# Configuring Bootstrap with XHTML

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, xhtml

I've built a (very) basic webform in standard XHTML, for an MVC project. I'm now wanting to enhance it, using Bootstrap.

I've been through a Bootstrap beginner course and the 'Getting Started' material. The problem I'm having is that they both use HTML5, and I'm unsure how to configure for XHTML.

When I copy the head content verbatim from the HTML template, I get syntax errors. I thought I'd managed to resolve them, but the XHTML body is now littered with 'not allowed here' errors. So I'm guessing there's still something fundamentally wrong with my XHTML. Summary of errors: -

- *Element style not allowed here*
- *Element section not allowed here*
- *Element form doesn't have required attribute action*
- *Element legend not allowed here*
- *Element placeholder not allowed here*
- *Element textarea doesn't have required attribute cols*

I've attached my initial basic XHTML webform, the HTML Bootstrap version and the modified XHTML Bootstrap version (including errors). I've also commented in the XHTML Bootstrap version, where the errors are.

*NB. you will notice JQuery function calls in the initial basic webform. I'll eventually build that into the Bootstrap configured version...just trying to get Bootstrap working with XHTML for now.*

Can anyone help?

**Initial Basic Webform - XHTML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Film Search</title>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery_utils.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">.ajaxTable tr:not(:first-child) { cursor: pointer; } </style>

</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" bgcolor="#20b2aa">
        <tr><th><big></big>Film Search Application</th></tr>
    </table>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Get All Films</legend>
        <form action="#">
            <input type="button" value="XML" onclick="getAllFilms('GetAllFilms', 'xml')"/>
            <input type="button" value="JSON" onclick="getAllFilms('GetAllFilms', 'json')"/>
            <input type="button" value="TEXT" onclick="getAllFilms('GetAllFilms', 'text')"/>
        </form>
        <div id="getallfilms"></div>
    </fieldset><br></br>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Get Films By Name</legend>
        <form action="#">
            <label>Film Name: <input type="text" id="filmname"/></label><br></br>
            <input type="button" value="XML"
                   onclick="getFilmsByName('GetFilmsByName', 'xml', 'filmname')"/>
            <input type="button" value="JSON"
                   onclick="getFilmsByName('GetFilmsByName', 'json', 'filmname')"/>
            <input type="button" value="TEXT"
                   onclick="getFilmsByName('GetFilmsByName', 'text', 'filmname')"/>
        </form>
        <div id="getfilmsbyname"></div>
    </fieldset><br></br>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Get Film By ID</legend>
        <form action="#">
            <label>Film ID: <input type="text" id="filmid"/></label><br></br>
            <input type="button" value="XML"
                   onclick="getFilmById('GetFilmById', 'xml', 'filmid')"/>
            <input type="button" value="JSON"
                   onclick="getFilmById('GetFilmById', 'json', 'filmid')"/>
            <input type="button" value="TEXT"
                   onclick="getFilmById('GetFilmById', 'text', 'filmid')"/>
        </form>
    </fieldset><br></br>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Update Film Details</legend>
        <form action="#">

            <label>Film Name: <input type="text" id="u_filmname"/></label><br></br>
            <label>Year: <input type="text" id="u_year"/></label><br></br>
            <label>Director: <input type="text" id="u_director"/></label><br></br>
            <label>Cast: <input type="text" id="u_stars"/></label><br></br>
            <label>Plot: <input type="text" id="u_review"/></label><br></br>

            <input type="button" value="XML"
                   onclick="updateFilm(
                       'filmid', 'u_filmname', 'u_year', 'u_director', 'u_stars', 'u_review',
                       'UpdateFilm', 'xml')"/>
            <input type="button" value="JSON"
                   onclick="updateFilm(
                       'filmid', 'u_filmname', 'u_year', 'u_director', 'u_stars', 'u_review',
                       'UpdateFilm', 'json')"/>
            <input type="button" value="TEXT"
                   onclick="updateFilm(
                       'filmid', 'u_filmname', 'u_year', 'u_director', 'u_stars', 'u_review',
                       'UpdateFilm', 'text')"/><br></br>

        </form>
        <div id="updatefilm"></div>
    </fieldset><br></br>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add New Film</legend>
        <form action="#">

            <label>Film Name: <input type="text" id="add_filmname"/></label><br></br>
            <label>Year: <input type="text" id="add_year"/></label><br></br>
            <label>Director: <input type="text" id="add_director"/></label><br></br>
            <label>Cast: <input type="text" id="add_stars"/></label><br></br>
            <label>Plot: <input type="text" id="add_review"/></label><br></br>

            <input type="button" value="XML"
                   onclick="addFilm(
                       'add_filmname', 'add_year', 'add_stars', 'add_director', 'add_review',
                       'AddFilm', 'xml')"/>

            <input type="button" value="JSON"
                   onclick="addFilm(
                       'add_filmname', 'add_year', 'add_stars', 'add_director', 'add_review',
                       'AddFilm', 'json')"/>

            <input type="button" value="TEXT"
                   onclick="addFilm(
                       'add_filmname', 'add_year', 'add_stars', 'add_director', 'add_review',
                       'AddFilm', 'text')"/>
        </form>
    </fieldset><br></br>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Delete Film</legend>
        <form action="#">
            <label>Film ID: <input type="text" id="deletefilmid"/></label><br></br>
            <input type="button" value="Delete Film"
                   onclick="deleteFilm('deletefilmid', 'DeleteFilm')"/>
        </form>
        <div id="deletefilm"></div>
    </fieldset><br></br>

    <!-- add single div id for table results -->
    <div id="filmtable"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Bootstrap Webform - HTML5**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- creates a class for handling colours -->
<style>
  :root {
    --h1colour: #6b52aa;
    --h2colour: #1c7430;
  }
</style>

<div class="container-md">
  <section class="content mt-4" id="filmdbapp">
    <!-- can now call variable-->
    <h3 style="color: var(--h1colour)">
      <strong>FILM DATABASE APPLICATION</strong></h3>
  </section>
  <form>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <div class="btn-group- mt-3 mb-3">
        <p>### STATIC ###</p>
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Get All Films</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add New Film</button>
      </div><!-- button group -->
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <h3 style="color: var(--h1colour)">
      <legend>Search Request</legend></h3>
    <input class="form-control mt-3 mb-3" type="text" id="searchinfo"
           placeholder="Enter film name or ID here">

    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"
             name="flexRadioDefault" id="jsonRadio">
      <label class="form-check-label mr-5" for="jsonRadio">JSON</label>

      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"
             name="flexRadioDefault" id="xmlRadio">
      <label class="form-check-label mr-5" for="xmlRadio">XML</label>

      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"
             name="flexRadioDefault" id="textRadio">
      <label class="form-check-label mr-5" for="textRadio">Text</label>
    </div><!-- form check -->

    <div class="btn-group- mt-3 mb-5">
      <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Get Film By Name</button>
      <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Get Film By ID</button>
    </div><!-- button group -->
  </div>
</div><br>

<div class="container-md">
  <p>### DYNAMIC ###</p>
  <form>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <!-- still struggling with this - might need to stick with 6 column table-->
      <div class="table-active mb-3">
        <table class="table">
          <thead><tr><th scope="col">FILM SEARCH RESULTS</th></tr></thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr><th scope="row">Film Name</th></tr>
          <tr><th scope="row">Year</th></tr>
          <tr><th scope="row">Main Cast</th></tr>
          <tr><th scope="row">Director</th></tr>
          <tr><th scope="row">Plot</th></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div><!-- table class -->
      <div class="btn-group- mt-3 mb-5">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
      </div><!-- button group -->

      <div class="form-group">
        <h3 style="color: var(--h1colour)">
          <legend>Add Film Details</legend></h3>
        <input class="form-control mt-3" type="text" id="filmName"
               placeholder="Film name">
        <input class="form-control mt-2" type="text" id="year"
               placeholder="Year">
        <textarea class="form-control mt-2" id="cast"
                  rows="2" placeholder="Main film cast"></textarea>
        <input class="form-control mt-2 mb-2" type="text" id="director"
               placeholder="Director">
        <textarea class="form-control mb-2" id="plot"
                  rows="4" placeholder="Film plot"></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add Film</button>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
          <h3 style="color: var(--h1colour)">
            <legend>Update Film Details</legend></h3>
          <input class="form-control mt-3" type="text" id="u_filmName"
                 placeholder="Film name">
          <input class="form-control mt-2" type="text" id="u_year"
                 placeholder="Year">
          <textarea class="form-control mt-2" id="u_cast"
                    rows="2" placeholder="Main film cast"></textarea>
          <input class="form-control mt-2 mb-2" type="text" id="u_director"
                 placeholder="Director">
          <textarea class="form-control mb-2" id="u_plot"
                    rows="4" placeholder="Film plot"></textarea>
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update Film</button>
        </div><br>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div><!-- container -->

<script src="js/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Bootstrap Configured Webform (including errors) - XHTML**
*I've annotated in the code block, where the 'not allowed here' errors occur*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Film Search</title>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script
            src="resources/js/jquery_utils.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="resources/js/jquery.slim.min.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="resources/js/popper.min.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            type="text/css"></script>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

</head>
<body>
<!-- creates a class for handling colours -->

**Element style not allowed here**

<style>
    :root {
        --h1colour: #6b52aa;
        --h2colour: #1c7430;
    }
</style>

<div class="container-md">

    **Element section not allowed here**

    <section class="content mt-4" id="filmdbapp">
        <!-- can now call variable-->
        <h3 style="color: var(--h1colour)">
            <strong>FILM DATABASE APPLICATION</strong></h3>
    </section>

    **Element form doesn't have required attribute action**

    <form>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-group- mt-3 mb-3">
                <p>### STATIC ###</p>
                <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Get All Films</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add New Film</button>
            </div><!-- button group -->
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <h3 style="color: var(--h1colour)">

            **Element legend not allowed here**

            <legend>Search Request</legend></h3>
        <input class="form-control mt-3 mb-3" type="text" id="searchinfo"

               **Element placeholder not allowed here**

               placeholder="Enter film name or ID here">

        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"
                   name="flexRadioDefault" id="jsonRadio">
            <label class="form-check-label mr-5" for="jsonRadio">JSON</label>

            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"
                   name="flexRadioDefault" id="xmlRadio">
            <label class="form-check-label mr-5" for="xmlRadio">XML</label>

            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"
                   name="flexRadioDefault" id="textRadio">
            <label class="form-check-label mr-5" for="textRadio">Text</label>
        </div><!-- form check -->

        <div class="btn-group- mt-3 mb-5">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Get Film By Name</button>
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Get Film By ID</button>
        </div><!-- button group -->
    </div>
</div><br>

<div class="container-md">
    <p>### DYNAMIC ###</p>
    <form>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="table-active mb-3">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead><tr><th scope="col">FILM SEARCH RESULTS</th></tr></thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr><th scope="row">Film Name</th></tr>
                    <tr><th scope="row">Year</th></tr>
                    <tr><th scope="row">Main Cast</th></tr>
                    <tr><th scope="row">Director</th></tr>
                    <tr><th scope="row">Plot</th></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div><!-- table class -->
            <div class="btn-group- mt-3 mb-5">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
            </div><!-- button group -->

            <div class="form-group">
                <h3 style="color: var(--h1colour)">
                    <legend>Add Film Details</legend></h3>
                <input class="form-control mt-3" type="text" id="filmName"
                       placeholder="Film name">
                <input class="form-control mt-2" type="text" id="year"
                       placeholder="Year">
                <textarea class="form-control mt-2" id="cast"
                          rows="2" placeholder="Main film cast"></textarea>
                <input class="form-control mt-2 mb-2" type="text" id="director"
                       placeholder="Director">

                **Element textarea doesn't have required attribute cols**

                <textarea class="form-control mb-2" id="plot"
                          rows="4" placeholder="Film plot"></textarea>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add Film</button>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3 style="color: var(--h1colour)">
                        <legend>Update Film Details</legend></h3>
                    <input class="form-control mt-3" type="text" id="u_filmName"
                           placeholder="Film name">
                    <input class="form-control mt-2" type="text" id="u_year"
                           placeholder="Year">
                    <textarea class="form-control mt-2" id="u_cast"
                              rows="2" placeholder="Main film cast"></textarea>
                    <input class="form-control mt-2 mb-2" type="text" id="u_director"
                           placeholder="Director">
                    <textarea class="form-control mb-2" id="u_plot"
                              rows="4" placeholder="Film plot"></textarea>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update Film</button>
                </div><br>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div><!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just don't. XHTML 1.0 Transitional was a stop gap measure from 20 years ago. If you want to use XHTML at all, use the XML syntax of HTML5, and remember to serve your pages with the `application/xhtml+xml` content type. This won't fix all your errors, some are mistakes in any version of HTML or XHTML, but it will eliminate some of them so you can concentrate on the rest.

Comment: thank you @Alohci. several people have said the same. we seem to have the worst comp sci tutor ever. this isn't the first time he's told us to use methods that are very outdated